# Recommendation based on Item History

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have a csv file/ table data in following format,

```
UserId Item1 Item2                  
1      url1   url3                                                                                     
1      url4   url6            
2      url2   url3         
2      url2   url4      
2      url4   url6     
3      url4   url6     
3      url2   url3
```

So, here I want to predict item2 for a perticular user if value of item1 is known. Can we use collaborative filtering for the same?? If yes, please guide :)

Comment: What you described so far could be a simple database query. `SELECT item2, count(*) FROM table WHERE item1 = '...' GROUP BY item2 ORDER BY COUNT(*)`. Do you have any more data? Does users vote/rate items?

Comment: No extra Data :( But there can be extra column which gives the count of no of times item2 is visited after item1. The reason for not using simple database query is, I want to find out similar users and recommend the item2 accordingly (I just want to try this don't know if it will work).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it would work, you've just got to figure out how you decide if a user is similar or not. The following gives you a suggestion field based on what item2 values have been paired with item1s (and vice versa) - it excludes items the user already has.. You can do much more complicated of course but here's something to get started

```sql
select *, ISNULL((SELECT STUFF
            ((SELECT ', ' + CAST(ITEM2 AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()] from
                    ((select top 5 ISNULL(item2,'') item2, count(item2) as cnt from items as CountTable1 where item1=Res.item1 and item2 is not null and len(item2) > 0
                     and item2 not in (select item2 from items where id=Res.id UNION select item1 from items where id=Res.id)
                    group by item2 order by cnt desc)
                    UNION
                    /* Below includes suggestions from item1 */
                    (select top 5 ISNULL(item1,'') item1, count(item1) as cnt from items as CountTable2 where item2=Res.item1 and item1 is not null and len(item1) > 0
                     and item1 not in (select item1 from items where id=Res.id UNION select item2 from items where id=Res.id)
                    group by item1 order by cnt desc))
                as Suggs where item1=Res.item1 FOR XML PATH('')
                , TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ')
        List_Output)
    ,'') as Suggestions from items as Res
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35413/9/0)